# Does dreamviewer imagemap "coords" property change wrt browser viewport size?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, imagemap

I have added image map on my map based web page.
Since it is supposed to work on different resolutions, hot-spots defined in the image map have to be dynamically changed when browser viewport size changes.

ex: when I initially place a hot-spot in India and change the browser size it should still 
placed on    India not in somewhere else.

I saw that there is a property called "coords" containing 3 parameters.

1. Does these properties dynamically change when it changes the browser viweport size?
2. Or can I make them dynamically changing?
3. Or going to javascript is recommended?

(As far as I tested they are fixed to absolute locations.)

Comment: Is the *image* dynamically changing its size in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka: Yes , the image on which "imagemaps" are created, changes its size dynamically.

Comment: I guess you'd have to use relative (percent) coordinates on the image map. Pixel coordinates won't scale. No idea whether Dreamweaver supports that, you'd have to try out

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on imagemaps and found that;

1. They do not dynamically change their position when it changes the browser viewport size
2. I didn't tried to change'em dynamically. Hopefully you may able to do it with javascript
3. javascript was the solution for my problem

with the use of javascript ;

Browser viewport width and height can be taken

And relative to that width or height you can position the elements

imagemaps in dreamviewer is not a solution for this matter

Comment: If you want to scale an image then I suggest SVG. Vectors don't degrade when you scale them up/down and with cool tools like Raphael you can easily make your SVG images clickable in different regions like having an image-map. They're also well supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg